# Какое решение реализации знака рубля правильнее и лучше?

Tags: css, шрифты

У меня есть 3 варианта:

1. **font-awesome**, ну, тут всё понятно:  + шрифт будет симпатичным, не паримся, - нельзя изменить начертание, если шрифт не прогрузился, то и не видим знак по-идее.
2. **svg**, дизайнер нарисует как хочет, а я вставляю отдельно или из спрайта: + получаем точно нужное начертание, - все минусы svg, проблемы Line-height, которые придётся решать хаками с отступами, проблема управление размером и цветом, который придётся переопределять fill-ом
3. **кодировка**: + можем применить любой шрифт, легко менять цвет, размер, - шрифты могут не прогрузиться, на разных устройствах не отобразиться(привет, айфоны), есть целых 2 кода, которые работают по-разному.

В некоторых я использовал SVG, Но мне стало неудобно. Решил внедрять его котом, но на отдельной странице шрифты применяются 50\50, в айфонах еще хуже. Тогда решил применять для рубля стандартный сброс шрифтов под устройство от медиум\вп:

```
font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
```

font-weight: bold;

При том использую вариант &#x20bd т.к. он лучше работает, выходит без засечек.
Есть еще вариант, использовать PTRouble шрифт. Минусы как у FA и хуже, т.к. тут нужно использовать разные числа\буквы, в нашем случае для начертания часто подходит "9". Если шрифт не прогрузится,то юзеры увидят в цене что-то такое: 123 56 9

*А как правильнее? Варианты "руб" и "р" не предлагать...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У знака рубля есть свой номер в Unicode. Нужно использовать именно его. Это позволит пользователям:

1. скопировать символ в буфер обмена вместе с остальным сообщением,
2. прочитать его экранным ридером.

Font-awesome не позволяет это делать (это не баг, а фича, поскольку обычно иконки и не должны копироваться или читаться).

Для картинки можно использовать alt для тех же целей, но этот подход устарел (зачем-то же символ в Unicode добавляли!)

Для того, чтобы символ отображался на всех устройствах, можно подключить для него отдельный шрифт. Можно даже использовать шрифт, состоящий только из одного символа (если используете Google Fonts - допишите &text=₽ к URL). Это не помешает скопировать текст в буфер обмена или прочитать его.

Comment: Ок, а как быть с разным отображением на айосях\маках и 2 кодировками судя по вики? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F 
я использую второе

Comment: @sinneren какими двумя кодировками? Почему вас устраивает разное отображение буквы `а` - но не устраивает разное отображение символа `₽`?

Comment: я ж не про ютф и вин. Я про &#8381; или &#x20bd;

Comment: @sinneren это один и тот же символ, просто его код записан в разных системах счисления.